# How do I calculate F?

Tags: functions

```
F(0) = -3
F(1) = 2
F(n) = F(n-2) + 2 * F(n-1)
```

How can I know what `f(5)` would be?

We got a bunch of sums like this, I was hoping that if someone could explain me how to do one I could do the others on my own.

Comment: find F(2), then F(3), .....

Comment: Use generating functions, methods involving matrices or look up in OEIS if you need general formula.

Comment: http://people.math.umass.edu/~lr7q/ps_files/teaching/math456/Week3.2.pdf

Comment: I don't understand people referencing general solutions, that's not what is asked, even tho the title is misleading. @LinAlg, there is a typo in the second formula and $C$ is not defined... wtf quality.

Comment: the general solution is the most elegant way to compute f(5), albeit not the fastest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
F(5)&=F(5-2)+2F(5-1)\\
&=F(3)+2F(4)\\
&=F(3-2)+2F(3-1)+2\Big(F(4-2)+2F(4-1)\Big)\\
&=F(1)+2F(2)+2F(2)+4F(3)\\
&=2+4F(2)+4F(3)\\
&=2+4\Big(F(2-2)+2F(2-1)\Big)+4\Big(F(3-2)+2F(3-1)\Big)\\
&=2+4F(0)+8F(1)+4F(1)+8F(2)\\
&=2-12+16+8+8\Big(F(2-2)+2F(2-1)\Big)\\
&=14-24+16F(1)\\
&=-10+32\\
&=22.
\end{align}

[Use Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=F%280%29+%3D+-3,+F%281%29+%3D+2,+F%28n%29+%3D+F%28n-2%29+%2B+2+*+F%28n-1%29) to check.

Comment: The books says `F(5)` is `22`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most basic solution involves going through values one by one up to 5:

$F(2)=F(0)+2\cdot F(1)=-3+2\cdot 2=1$

$F(3) = F(1) + 2\cdot F(2)=2 +2\cdot 1=4$

etc.

Comment: `1 + 2 * 1 = 3` but you wrote `4` am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Sorry.  $F(1)=2$.  I'll correct it.

Answer (score 0):

the characteristic equation is
$x^2-2x-1=0$ which have one solution
$x=1$  .

so,

$F(n)=(a+bn)1^n=a+bn$

$F(0)=-3$ gives $a=-3$

$F(1)=2$ gives $a+b=2$
thus
$b=5$

and

$F(5)=22$

$(F_n)$ is arithmetic.

Comment: sorry i made a mistake in characteristic equation.